# Read_line() don´t wait for users input in loop. Rust

Tags: loops, rust, match, stdin

### What program shoud do?

1. Read two numbers separated by space from terminal e.g. "10 8".
2. Split the string to `Vec<&str>`.
3. Parse `Vec[0]` and `Vec[1]` to `num1` and `num2`.
4. Read (math) operation from terminal and parse it.
5. Print the "math" and result. (10 * 80 = 80)
6. Catch almost every error in steps 2. - 4. and run `try_again` function.
7. If all goes right than run `try_again` function with "Success" `msg`

(the `main` function is there only for context,
the problem is in `try_again` function)

```rust
use std::io::{self, Write, Read, Error, ErrorKind};

const ERR_MSG_STDIN_READ: &str = "Problem with getting input";
const ERR_MSG_STDOUT_FLUSH: &str = "Problem with flushing stdout";

fn main() {
    loop {
        clear_terminal();

        print!("Write 2 ints separated by space: ");
        let mut nums_string = String::new();
        io::stdout().flush().expect(ERR_MSG_STDOUT_FLUSH);
        io::stdin().read_line(&mut nums_string).expect(ERR_MSG_STDIN_READ);
        let nums_str_vec: Vec<&str> = nums_string.trim()
.split(' ').collect();
        let num1: i32 = match nums_str_vec[0].parse() {
            Ok(num) => num,
            Err(_) => match try_again("Error") {
                true => continue,
                false => break
            }
        };
        let num2: i32 = match nums_str_vec[1].parse() {
            Ok(num) => num,
            Err(_) => match try_again("Error") {
                true => continue,
                false => break
            }
        };

        print!("Write one of these[+,-,*,/] maths operation for 2 inputed ints: ");
        let mut operation_string = String::new();
        io::stdout().flush().expect(ERR_MSG_STDOUT_FLUSH);
        io::stdin().read_line(&mut operation_string).expect(ERR_MSG_STDIN_READ);
        let operation = match operation_string.trim().parse() {
            Ok(char) => char,
            Err(_) => match try_again("Error") {
                true => continue,
                false => break
            }
        };
        match operation {
            '+' => println!("{} {} {} = {}", num1, operation, num2, num1 + num2),
            '-' => println!("{} {} {} = {}", num1, operation, num2, num1 - num2),
            '*' => println!("{} {} {} = {}", num1, operation, num2, num1 * num2),
            '/' => println!("{} {} {} = {} ({})", num1, operation, num2, num1 / num2, num1 % num2),
            _ => match try_again("Error") {
                true => continue,
                false => break
            }
        }
        io::stdin().read(&mut [0]).expect(ERR_MSG_STDIN_READ);
        match try_again("Success") {
            true => continue,
            false => break
        }
    }
}

fn clear_terminal() {
    print!("{}c", 27 as char);
    io::stdout().flush().expect(ERR_MSG_STDOUT_FLUSH);
}
```

#### What `try_again` function shoud do?

1. Save `msg` to `msg_new` for later changing.
2. Read (y/n) answer from terminal and parse it.
3. If 'y' return `true` if 'n' return `false`.
4. Catch almost every error in step 2. and continue "self loop" again. (With "Error" `msg`)
5. The program (in `main` function) match returned result of `try_again` function => true means continue main loop, false means break the loop and end the program.

```rust
fn try_again(msg: &str) -> bool {
    let mut msg_new = msg;
    loop {
        println!("The calculation end up with {}.", msg_new);
        print!("Do you want to make antoher calculation? (y/n): ");
        let mut answer_string = String::new();
        stdout().flush().expect(ERR_MSG_STDOUT_FLUSH);
        stdin().read_line(&mut answer_string).expect(ERR_MSG_STDIN_READ);
        match answer_string.trim().chars().next() {
            Some('y') => true,
            Some('n') => false,
            _ => {
                msg_new = "Error";
                continue
            }
        };  
    }
}
```

## Whats the problem?

### What doesn´t work in program?

step 7 *(maybe we can say 6 and 7)* the problem is in `try_again` function.

### What doesn´t work in `try_again` function

When the program run `try_again("Success");`:

1. In the first loop `stdin().read_line(&mut next_string)` doesn´t wait for users input and immediately go to `_ =>` arm.
2. And continue "self loop" again (with "Error" `msg`)
3. In the second loop actually wait for input and work but with wrong `msg`.

## Final question

**Why the `stdin().read_line(&mut next_string)` wait for input in secodn round of loop? How to solve it? Thanks for every answer!**

---

I am **totally** new to rust, please explain *everything* what you write.
OS: Windows 10, terminal: cmd (Command Promt)

Comment: You forgot the `break` in `try_again()`: `Some('y') => break true,` - also in the `'n'` arm.

Comment: First that didn´t help, still same. Second can you please explain why? If I write `true` it shoud be same as `return true` and if I return than the functions end, so loop end to, or not?

Comment: Probably there is a 2nd error in the program. If you write `true` it is **not** the same as `return true`. You never leave the `loop`. The `read` over `match try_again("Success")`  seems to be superfluous - comment the whole line out.

Comment: Because variables can be used directly in the `format!` string the `match operation` lines can be written like this: `'+' => println!("{num1} {operation} {num2} = {}", num1 + num2),`.

Answer (score 1):

You must check whether a `'y'` or a `'n'` was entered at all, e.g. with a guard:

```
fn next(msg: &str) -> bool {
    let msg_new = msg;
    loop {
        clear_terminal();
    
        println!("The calculation end up with {}.", msg_new);
        print!("Do you want to make antoher calculation? (y/n): ");
        let mut next_string = String::new();
        stdout().flush().expect(ERR_MSG_STDOUT_FLUSH);
        match std::io::stdin().read_line(&mut next_string) {
            Ok(n) if n > 0 && next_string.chars().next().unwrap() == 'y' => break true,
            Ok(n) if n > 0 && next_string.chars().next().unwrap() == 'n' => break false,
            Ok(_) => {},  // other input is ignored
            Err(err) => panic_any(err),
        };
    }
}
```

Btw: `next` should be reserved for iterators

Comment: Bro that not even working still same scenario.

Comment: I didn't check the input size. Try it again.

Comment: thaks, after small change from Err and Ok(_) to _ => ... its usable but, not sure if its perfect I gonna trying find some other options.

Comment: There is little leeway here to design the solution differently, but good luck.

Comment: "Btw: next should be reserved for iterators" Not really...

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo I mean as function name? Something as `await` or `input` would be clearer here.

Comment: Although you rarely if ever see the system error `Err(err)`, it shouldn't be mixed up with the handling of malformed user input belonging to `Ok(_)`.

Comment: Ok I think your solutions work but after some testing and building I have same sceanario. I am gonna edit my q.